# Loading data from file to oracle table using python

Tags: python, oracle, list

```
import cx_Oracle
con=cx_Oracle.connect("SYSTEM/123456@localhost:1521/xe")
print("conected to oracle db")
q='CREATE TABLE EMP2(id VARCHAR2(4),FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(40),LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30), DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(10), Phone_number VARCHAR2(10), Address VARCHAR2(100), salary VARCHAR2(100))'
s="insert into EMP2 (id,first_name,last_name,department,phone_number,address,salary) values (:0,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)"
con=con.cursor()
con.execute(q)
records=[]
file=open("C:\\Users\\Shrishubh\\Downloads\\employees (2).txt")
for i in file.readlines():
    records.append(i.split("/ "))
print(records)
for i in records:
    con.executemany(s,records)
```

The above code is loading data from txt file to oracle dB using list in python. Code is getting executed but no data is getting loaded in table EMP2.Need help for the same.

Comment: See the cx_Oracle manual [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgot about commiting your changes. Try adding:

```
con.commit()
```

To the very end of your code. Like this:

```
import cx_Oracle
con=cx_Oracle.connect("SYSTEM/123456@localhost:1521/xe")
print("conected to oracle db")
q='CREATE TABLE EMP2(id VARCHAR2(4),FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(40),LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30), DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(10), Phone_number VARCHAR2(10), Address VARCHAR2(100), salary VARCHAR2(100))'
s="insert into EMP2 (id,first_name,last_name,department,phone_number,address,salary) values (:0,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)"
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute(q)
records=[]
file=open("C:\\Users\\Shrishubh\\Downloads\\employees (2).txt")
for i in file.readlines():
    records.append(i.split("/ "))
print(records)
for i in records:
    cur.executemany(s,records)
con.commit()
```

Comment: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit' getting this error.

Comment: @ShubhamBhoyar I've just updated an answer due to your issue. Please, try it again :)

Comment: @ShubhamBhoyar please mark this answer as solution if that helped

Comment: File contains only 10 records but in table 100 records are getting loaded.

Comment: You're executing `executemany` for `records` times. In your code: ```for i in records: cur.executemany(s, records)```. Try removing the loop and execute plain ```cur.executemany(s, records)```

Answer (score 0):

From the cx_Oracle manual  [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html):

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

. . .

# Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)

# Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
batch_size = 10000

with open('testsp.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sql = "insert into test (id,name) values (:1, :2)"
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0], line[1]))
        if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
            data = []
    if data:
        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
```